# Trying to solve this simple C++ program, but I am stuck somewhere

Tags: c++

This is as far as I got, not so strong in understanding math and cpp. Maybe someone could help a little bit, sitting for three hours to find solution. I have an understanding a bit about (i = 1; i <= 49; ++i), but I am just stuck somewhere. I started cpp recently so I am trying to solve some exercises.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

// program should multiply numbers as showed below
// S = 1∗2 + 2∗3 + 3∗4 + ⋯ + 49∗50

int main()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i <= 49; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 2; i <= 50; ++j)
        {
            cout << i * j << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is very vague and does not convey exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question to adhere to the StackOverflow standards.

Comment: in your example, you were computing `1*1 + 1*2 + ... 2*1 + 2*2 + .. 49*1 + ... + 49*50`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop.

you will always multiply each number `i` with the next number `i+1` so one loop is enough.

here is a solution

```cpp
for (i = 1; i <= 49; ++i) {
   cout << i * (i+1) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Hello Aviad. Ok, I see now where I failed. Thank you for this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Nested loops are not required,

```
int main(){
   int i;
   int sum = 0;
   for(i = 0; i <= 49; i++){
      sum += i * (i + 1);
   }
}
```

This program added the current index `i` and the next index `i + 1` to a variable named `sum`.

After the for loop is concluded, the sum of the products should be available in the variable `sum`.

Comment: This one is also great way to write a program. Thanks Leo.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Aviad's answer (and seeming as your question has been answered twice), I would like to give you a tip when it comes to C++ programming.
You'll see a lot of tutorials showing to use the following: `using namespace <whatever>`.

You should avoid `using` an entire namespace, as this will pollute your application's namespace. 
Essentially what this means, is that the compiler is looking at **each and every** entry (be it a further namespace, function, variable, what-have-you) and will include a little reference to each member it has found.
This can be especially problematic when it comes to using multiple functions with the same names and parameters.

Suppose you have following code:

```
void myFoo(uint32_t& bar) {
    // do some cool stuff
}
```

and let's assume the *std* namespace has the same function, which does something completely different.

When you call the code like this:

```
int main(int32_t argCount, char* argValues[]) {
    myFoo(argCount); // this is where it'll clash
    return 0;
}
```

Either the compiler (or linker) will generate an error, saying the type is ambiguous or in some rare cases the compiler will decide for you, which of these functions it'll use.
This can cause some nasty bugs if the functions do similar tasks.

Comment: Simon, thank you for the advice. It is really cool that people are so helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple typo in the inner loop

```
for (j = 2; i <= 50; ++j)
```

The condition `i <= 50` should rather be `j <= 50`.
This is the reason, why your inner loop never ends.

Apart from that, look at @Aviad's answer.

Comment: Thank Olaf for explaining me this.